# How can I get the friendly name of a MFi bluetooth device in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, mfi, external-accessory

So [EAAccessory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html) provides a property to retrieve the name of a device. From the devices I have queried, this usually is not the same as the friendly name you see in the `Settings > Bluetooth` page. It is usually a generic model name of the device.

Is there a way with an `EAAccessory`, or some other class to get the friendly name of the device?

Comment: I have run into the same issue. Did you ever find out the answer? Is it possible in iOS7?

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet